# Translating back "悪即斬" from the portuguese adaptation "Justice. Here. Now"

Tags: translation

When I was little, I remember watching a Brazilian Portuguese subbed version of Rurouni Kenshin (here more widely known as Samurai X) and catching one of the main characters Saito frequently saying the phrase:

> Justice. Here. Now.

Which is a veeery loose translation of *Aku Soku Zan*, which is frequently translated as "Slay Evil Immediately".

Given the Portuguese version "Justice. Here. Now" is considerably far from the English "Slay Evil Immediately" in meaning, I wonder how this phrase "Justice. Here. Now" motto would be best represented in Japanese. Maybe it indeed maps into something similar to "Aku Soku Zan" even though the difference between both translations in English is so big?

Comment: 「正義、只今参上」とかでいかがですかね？

Comment: I don't know about the claim in the earlier answer that "the phrase is bad Classical Chinese" and "the Ruroni Kenshin catchphrase is an uneducated riff on Chinese philosophical statements like 心即理". I think there's a good chance that it's a false association and the phrase's similarity to ancient Chinese maxims like 心即理  is only superficial and accidental.

Comment: I mean it's been our thing for some time to slap kanji together to coin cool-sounding names for moves and techniques in manga and stuff. I'd just take it as a convention of how we use the Japanese language without reference to Classical Chinese.  「悪即斬」 is "grammatical" on its own terms and to me feels already Japanese enough.

Comment: Huh, so it looks like a few of my assumptions were wrong. Rewording the question.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder how this phrase "Justice. Here. Now" motto would be best represented in Japanese.

Translating this into a regular Japanese sentence is easy; something like 今ここに正義を為す should work (今 = now, ここに = here, 正義 = justice, 為す = perform/execute). However, this completely ignores the rhythmical or aesthetic quality of the original phrase 悪即斬.

Note that the original phrase is not a regular Japanese sentence but a made-up three-kanji jukugo, or "idiomatic compound". And it's extremely challenging to translate "Justice. Here. Now." back into a three-kanji jukugo. Forming a creative jukugo is not something ordinary people do, and there are lots of constraints. It's more or less like asking for the best English single word for "Justice. Here. Now." using only Latinate affixes.

"Justice. Here. Now." sounds a little peculiar as regular English, but it at least respects the rhythm of the original phrase, and I think it's a nice translation. And it's not very far from the original meaning, since 即 roughly means "here and now".

(BTW, I don't know how 悪即斬 sounds to Chinese speakers, but that's not important. Linguistically the two languages are very different except that Japanese borrowed characters from Chinese.)

Comment: Oh cool to know that the portuguese version is not as bad as I though. I suspected it was off because none of the other translations I've seen mention a place concept ("here"), just time concepts ("swiftly", "immediately"), though in retrospect "immediate" also can be used for places. Thanks for explaining the challenge and TIL about jukugo.